# The Border and Padding styles in the text field do not apply in swift5

Tags: ios, css, swift, iphone, border-layout

I am currently working on the `iOS` project. My problem is that nothing in the `textfield` changes me. It's hard to find an answer to what's wrong. How should I change it?

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class passwrodCheckAlertController : UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var passModalAlert: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var passTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelbutton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var okButton: UIButton!



//    let color = UIColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    let color = UIColor.red
    let insets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 31.7, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.passModalAlert.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        self.passTextfield.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        self.passTextfield.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        self.passModalAlert.textContainerInset = insets
        changeViewFont()
    }

}

class PaddingTextField : UITextField {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 100, bottom: 0, right: 15))
        return bounds
    }

}
```

**MainStoryboard**

[image: MainStoryboard]

**Screen not change**

[image: screen field]

`CornerRadius` in text view works very well.

Thanks in advance

---

### Edit start

I listened to the comments and used the `leftview`. And the gap problem was solved. But still my `Border` style doesn't change.

```swift
        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: self.passTextfield.frame.height))
        self.passTextfield.leftView = paddingView
        self.passTextfield.leftViewMode = .always
        self.passTextfield.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        self.passTextfield.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        self.passModalAlert.textContainerInset = insets
```

[image: change]

> `Border` style doesn't change.

---

### Edit Second start

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var passTextfield: PaddingTextField!
...
class PaddingTextField : UITextField {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        //set your border style here
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 15))
        return bounds
    }

}
```

> But this has not changed anything changed.

Comment: You need to add leftView in UITextfield.

Comment: Hi @RushabhCShah  What is leftView ???

Comment: Leftview is a property of UITextfield in that you can assign as a clear view.
For Leftview documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619597-leftview

Comment: @RushabhCShah So why doesn't the Border style work?

Comment: Solved or can I give you the code and explain?

Comment: @RushabhCShah  Could you look at my revised question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue seems to be your setUp when you created the outlet you should select PaddingTextField instead of UITextField as UITextField is a superclass and does not know anything about the additional functionality that it's children have.

Delete the IBOutlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var passTextfield: UITextField!
```

and recreate it it should look like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var passTextfield: PaddingTextField!
```

hope this helps.

In regards to the border:

```
class PaddingTextField : UITextField {

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       //set your border style here
       self.layer.cornerRadius = 3
       // Add borderWidth as otherwise you are having a 0 point wide border
       self.layer.borderWidth = 5 
       self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
   }

   override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
       bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 100, bottom: 0, right: 15))
       return bounds
   }

}
```

runs as expected:
[image]

Comment: Does this apply to the border style as well?

Comment: it should do however I would set those in class PaddingTextField : UITextField and using the awakeFromNib method which gets called when views get instantiated from the StoryBoard

Comment: I solved the problem of 'editingRect' with 'leftview'. So there is no need to change. Now my problem is that the Border style does not change. Will 'PaddingTextField' resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you look at my revised question?

Comment: Look at my revised question. I tried to your answer

Comment: Get rid of the required init

Comment: init?? Where do you mean to run `init`?

Comment: Where you declare your class PaddingTextField delete the required init? As it is not needed when you use the storyboards

Comment: I missed one more thing you are not adding any line as you have not set the borderWidth. Check my latest edit it should be fine

Comment: Glad that I could help